# Adding a value to the front of a TreeMap

Tags: java

Previously I had the TreeMap that is sorted via:

```
Map<String, Set<Stuff>> map = new TreeMap<>(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

I'm thinking of adding a special case. If the string is "Front", I want to ignore this ordering and just have it in the beginning of the map.

```
Map<String, Set<Stuff>> map = new TreeMap<>((s1, s2) -> {
    //do a check to see if the string is "Front", otherwise use the above
});
```

This feels a bit convoluted to me... Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Nope, that is the way. You can create the `Comparator` as a separate class for re-use using `new`, or as a static method for re-use using method reference like you're using `compareToIgnoreCase`, instead of as a lambda as you're trying to do, but you still have to write the code somewhere.

Comment: Comparators can be chained with andThen, but in fact the shown approach is probably just as short. Why not simply add "\u0001" or "\u0001Front" in front?